# Make C# Console Application Close after Return Value

Tags: c#, text, md5

I have a program that loads a file, MD5 Hash'es it, and outputs the Hash to a new text file. It works well, but I have one issue. After it outputs the file successfully, the console window doesn't close automatically, and as a result, one must close the window in order for the program to exit. How would I make it exit on its own?

code:

```
string hash = GetHash("1.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("Hash: {0}", hash);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string GetHash(string pathSrc)
    {
        string pathDest = "copy_" + pathSrc;

        File.Copy(pathSrc, pathDest, true);

        String md5Result;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(pathDest))
        {
            foreach (Byte b in md5Hasher.ComputeHash(fs))
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }

        md5Result = sb.ToString();

        File.Delete(pathDest);

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("8.txt");
        tw.WriteLine(md5Result);
        tw.Close();

        
        return md5Result;
```

Comment: Don't read input from the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried getting rid of the Console.ReadKey()?

Comment: Thanks! not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 4):

Remove this line

```
Console.ReadKey();
```